# Minimum of a potential function

Tags: analysis, spherical-coordinates

I'm looking for extremes (minimum) of
$$V = \frac{\alpha}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|} + \beta (\vec{r}_1 + \vec{r}_2)\cdot \vec{e}_z$$
where $\vec{r}_i = R(\cos\phi_i\sin\theta_i,\sin\phi_i\sin\theta_i,\cos\theta_i)$. I though that the expansion to spherical harmonics would be the easiest way
$$
V(\phi_1,\phi_2,\theta_1,\theta_2) = \frac{\alpha}{R} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{4 \pi}{2m + 1} \sum_{l=-m}^{m}Y_{l m}(\phi_1,\theta_1) Y_{l m}^{*}(\phi_2,\theta_2) + \beta R(\cos\theta_1+\cos\theta_2).$$
As you see, I am looking for $\phi_i$ and $\theta_i$ for both vectors.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what kind of physics problem is this? My guess would be two particles of equal charge in a vertical electric field and confined to the surface of the sphere... (That might also provide some aide in seeing where the minimum should occur.)

Comment: Two particles with equal charge and mass that can move in a half sphere.

Comment: Ah, so gravity in lieu of electric field. Though, where is the half sphere in the problem statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By direct expansion of the vectors, you could see that $$V({\phi _1},{\theta _1},{\phi _2},{\theta _2}) = \frac{\alpha }{{\sqrt 2 R\sqrt {1 - \cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})\sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} }} + \beta R(cos{\theta _1} + cos{\theta _2})
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiabdAfawjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaa
% BaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGaeiilaWIaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabig
% daXaqabaGccqGGSaalcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiab
% cYcaSiabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeiykaKIaeyypa0
% ZaaSaaaeaacqaHXoqyaeaadaGcaaqaaiabikdaYaWcbeaakiabdkfa
% snaakaaabaGaeGymaeJaeyOeI0Iagi4yamMaei4Ba8Maei4CamNaeq
% iUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWC
% cqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabgkHiTiGbcogaJjabc+
% gaVjabcohaZjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGa
% eyOeI0Iaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGGPaqkcyGGZb
% WCcqGGPbqAcqGGUbGBcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiGb
% cohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaa
% qabaaaaOGaey4kaSIaeqOSdiMaemOuaiLaeiikaGIaei4yamMaei4B
% a8Maei4CamNaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccqGHRaWkcq
% GGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaa
% kiabcMcaPaaa!94EC!
$$Now, we shall evaluate the derivative of the potential function with respect to the variables. Again by direct calculation, we could see that:$$\begin{array}{l}\frac{{\partial V({\phi _1},{\theta _1},{\phi _2},{\theta _2})}}{{\partial {\phi _1}}} =  - \frac{{\alpha \sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}\sin ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})}}{{2\sqrt 2 R{{\left( {1 - \cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})\sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}}},\\\frac{{\partial V({\phi _1},{\theta _1},{\phi _2},{\theta _2})}}{{\partial {\theta _1}}} = \frac{{\alpha \left( {\sin {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})\cos {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)}}{{2\sqrt 2 R{{\left( {1 - \cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})\sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}}} - \beta R\sin {\theta _1},\\\frac{{\partial V({\phi _1},{\theta _1},{\phi _2},{\theta _2})}}{{\partial {\phi _2}}} = \frac{{\alpha \sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}\sin ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})}}{{2\sqrt 2 R{{\left( {1 - \cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})\sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}}},\\\frac{{\partial V({\phi _1},{\theta _1},{\phi _2},{\theta _2})}}{{\partial {\theta _2}}} =  - \frac{{\alpha \left( {\cos {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2} - \cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})\sin {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2}} \right)}}{{2\sqrt 2 R{{\left( {1 - \cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})\sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}}} - \beta R\sin {\theta _2}.\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOabaeqabaWaaSaaaeaacqGHciITcqWG
% wbGvcqGGOaakcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiabcYcaSi
% abeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGaeiilaWIaeqy1dy2aaSba
% aSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGGSaalcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmai
% dabeaakiabcMcaPaqaaiabgkGi2kabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqm
% aeqaaaaakiabg2da9iabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaeqySdeMagi4CamNaei
% yAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGZbWC
% cqGGPbqAcqGGUbGBcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiGbco
% haZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqm
% aeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGGPa
% qkaeaacqaIYaGmdaGcaaqaaiabikdaYaWcbeaakiabdkfasnaabmaa
% baGaeGymaeJaeyOeI0Iagi4yamMaei4Ba8Maei4CamNaeqiUde3aaS
% baaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqC
% daWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabgkHiTiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabco
% haZjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Ia
% eqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGGPaqkcyGGZbWCcqGGPb
% qAcqGGUbGBcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiGbcohaZjab
% cMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaaGccaGLOa
% GaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaadaWcaaqaaiabiodaZaqaaiabikdaYaaa
% aaaaaOGaeiilaWcabaWaaSaaaeaacqGHciITcqWGwbGvcqGGOaakcq
% aHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiabcYcaSiabeI7aXnaaBaaa
% leaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGaeiilaWIaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYa
% qabaGccqGGSaalcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabcMca
% PaqaaiabgkGi2kabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaaaakiabg2
% da9maalaaabaGaeqySde2aaeWaaeaacyGGZbWCcqGGPbqAcqGGUbGB
% cqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabco
% haZjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iagi4yamMa
% ei4Ba8Maei4CamNaeiikaGIaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqaba
% GccqGHsislcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabcMcaPiGb
% cogaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaO
% Gagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqa
% baaakiaawIcacaGLPaaaaeaacqaIYaGmdaGcaaqaaiabikdaYaWcbe
% aakiabdkfasnaabmaabaGaeGymaeJaeyOeI0Iagi4yamMaei4Ba8Ma
% ei4CamNaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGJbWycqGGVb
% WBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabgkHiTiGb
% cogaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXa
% qmaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGG
% PaqkcyGGZbWCcqGGPbqAcqGGUbGBcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymae
% dabeaakiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaI
% YaGmaeqaaaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaadaWcaaqaaiabio
% daZaqaaiabikdaYaaaaaaaaOGaeyOeI0IaeqOSdiMaemOuaiLagi4C
% amNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccq
% GGSaalaeaadaWcaaqaaiabgkGi2kabdAfawjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaa
% BaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGaeiilaWIaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabig
% daXaqabaGccqGGSaalcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiab
% cYcaSiabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeiykaKcabaGaey
% OaIyRaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaaaaOGaeyypa0ZaaSaa
% aeaacqaHXoqycyGGZbWCcqGGPbqAcqGGUbGBcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcba
% GaeGymaedabeaakiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaa
% leaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeiikaGIaeq
% y1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccqGHsislcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWc
% baGaeGOmaidabeaakiabcMcaPaqaaiabikdaYmaakaaabaGaeGOmai
% daleqaaOGaemOuai1aaeWaaeaacqaIXaqmcqGHsislcyGGJbWycqGG
% VbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiGbcogaJj
% abc+gaVjabcohaZjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyOe
% I0Iagi4yamMaei4Ba8Maei4CamNaeiikaGIaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaai
% abigdaXaqabaGccqGHsislcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaa
% kiabcMcaPiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacq
% aIXaqmaeqaaOGagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqa
% aiabikdaYaqabaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWcbeqaamaalaaaba
% GaeG4mamdabaGaeGOmaidaaaaaaaGccqGGSaalaeaadaWcaaqaaiab
% gkGi2kabdAfawjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaO
% GaeiilaWIaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccqGGSaalcqaH
% vpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabcYcaSiabeI7aXnaaBaaale
% aacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeiykaKcabaGaeyOaIyRaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqa
% aiabikdaYaqabaaaaOGaeyypa0JaeyOeI0YaaSaaaeaacqaHXoqyda
% qadaqaaiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaI
% XaqmaeqaaOGagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaai
% abikdaYaqabaGccqGHsislcyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqGGOaak
% cqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiabgkHiTiabew9aMnaaBa
% aaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeiykaKIagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4Ma
% eqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZb
% WCcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaaaqa
% aiabikdaYmaakaaabaGaeGOmaidaleqaaOGaemOuai1aaeWaaeaacq
% aIXaqmcqGHsislcyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWc
% baGaeGymaedabeaakiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZjabeI7aXnaaBa
% aaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iagi4yamMaei4Ba8Maei4CamNa
% eiikaGIaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccqGHsislcqaHvp
% GzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabcMcaPiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjab
% c6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGagi4CamNaeiyAaK
% MaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaaakiaawIcacaGL
% PaaadaahaaWcbeqaamaalaaabaGaeG4mamdabaGaeGOmaidaaaaaaa
% GccqGHsislcqaHYoGycqWGsbGucyGGZbWCcqGGPbqAcqGGUbGBcqaH
% 4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabc6caUaaaaa!15E6!
$$ Now to find an extreme, we have to solve the equations above when they are all zero. Solving these equations is quite straightforward. First consider the case $\sin {\theta _1} = 0$. We have to satisfy only the second and fourth equations. This would lead to $$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}\cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2})\sin {\theta _2} = 0\\\left( {\frac{\alpha }{{2\sqrt 2 R{{\left( {1 - \cos {\theta _2}} \right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}}} + \beta R} \right)\sin {\theta _2} = 0\end{array} \right. \to \left\{ \begin{array}{l}\sin {\theta _2} = 0\\{\rm{or}}\\\cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2}) = 0,\cos {\theta _2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{\alpha }{{{R^2}\beta }}} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}\end{array} \right.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaamaaceaaeaqabeaacyGGJbWycqGG
% VbWBcqGGZbWCcqGGOaakcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaaki
% abgkHiTiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeiykaKIagi4C
% amNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccq
% GH9aqpcqaIWaamaeaadaqadaqaamaalaaabaGaeqySdegabaGaeGOm
% aiZaaOaaaeaacqaIYaGmaSqabaGccqWGsbGudaqadaqaaiabigdaXi
% abgkHiTiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaI
% YaGmaeqaaaGccaGLOaGaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaadaWcaaqaaiabio
% daZaqaaiabikdaYaaaaaaaaOGaey4kaSIaeqOSdiMaemOuaifacaGL
% OaGaayzkaaGagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaai
% abikdaYaqabaGccqGH9aqpcqaIWaamaaGaay5EaaGaeyOKH46aaiqa
% aqaabeqaaiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacq
% aIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyypa0JaeGimaadabaGaee4Ba8MaeeOCaihabaGa
% gi4yamMaei4Ba8Maei4CamNaeiikaGIaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabig
% daXaqabaGccqGHsislcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiab
% cMcaPiabg2da9iabicdaWiabcYcaSiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZj
% abeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyypa0JaeGymaeJaeyOe
% I0YaaSaaaeaacqaIXaqmaeaacqaIYaGmaaWaaeWaaeaadaWcaaqaai
% abeg7aHbqaaiabdkfasnaaCaaaleqabaGaeGOmaidaaOGaeqOSdiga
% aaGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqabaWaaSaaaeaacqaIYaGmaeaacq
% aIZaWmaaaaaaaakiaawUhaaaaa!A8FB!
$$ (The case for $\sin {\theta _2} = 0
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjab
% eI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyypa0JaeGimaadaaa!47FF!
$ is also very similar to this case and would yield $$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}\sin {\theta _1} = 0\\{\rm{or}}\\\cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2}) = 0,\cos {\theta _1} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{\alpha }{{{R^2}\beta }}} \right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}\end{array} \right.
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaamaaceaaeaqabeaacyGGZbWCcqGG
% PbqAcqGGUbGBcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiabg2da9i
% abicdaWaqaaiabb+gaVjabbkhaYbqaaiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabcoha
% ZjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iaeq
% y1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGGPaqkcqGH9aqpcqaIWaam
% cqGGSaalcyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeG
% ymaedabeaakiabg2da9iabigdaXiabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaeGymaeda
% baGaeGOmaidaamaabmaabaWaaSaaaeaacqaHXoqyaeaacqWGsbGuda
% ahaaWcbeqaaiabikdaYaaakiabek7aIbaaaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaah
% aaWcbeqaamaalaaabaGaeGOmaidabaGaeG4mamdaaaaaaaGccaGL7b
% aaaaa!7095!
$$). The final case arises when $\sin ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2}) = 0
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjab
% cIcaOiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iaeqy1dy
% 2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGGPaqkcqGH9aqpcqaIWaamaaa!4D9E!
$. Under this condition, we have $$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}\frac{{\alpha \left( {\sin {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \cos {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)}}{{2\sqrt 2 R{{\left( {1 - \cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}}} - \beta R\sin {\theta _1} = 0\\\frac{{\alpha \left( {\cos {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2} - \sin {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2}} \right)}}{{2\sqrt 2 R{{\left( {1 - \cos {\theta _1}\cos {\theta _2} - \sin {\theta _1}\sin {\theta _2}} \right)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}}} + \beta R\sin {\theta _2} = 0\end{array} \right. \to \sin {\theta _1} + \sin {\theta _2} = 0
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaamaaceaaeaqabeaadaWcaaqaaiab
% eg7aHnaabmaabaGagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaS
% qaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWg
% aaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabgkHiTiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZj
% abeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOB
% a4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaaae
% aacqaIYaGmdaGcaaqaaiabikdaYaWcbeaakiabdkfasnaabmaabaGa
% eGymaeJaeyOeI0Iagi4yamMaei4Ba8Maei4CamNaeqiUde3aaSbaaS
% qaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWg
% aaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabgkHiTiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUj
% abeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOB
% a4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaaakiaawIcacaGLPaaada
% ahaaWcbeqaamaalaaabaGaeG4mamdabaGaeGOmaidaaaaaaaGccqGH
% sislcqaHYoGycqWGsbGucyGGZbWCcqGGPbqAcqGGUbGBcqaH4oqCda
% WgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiabg2da9iabicdaWaqaamaalaaabaGa
% eqySde2aaeWaaeaacyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaa
% WcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaa
% BaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4
% MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGG
% ZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaaa
% qaaiabikdaYmaakaaabaGaeGOmaidaleqaaOGaemOuai1aaeWaaeaa
% cqaIXaqmcqGHsislcyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaa
% WcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiGbcogaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZjabeI7aXnaa
% BaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4
% MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccyGGZbWCcqGGPbqAcqGG
% UbGBcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaaaOGaayjkaiaawMcaam
% aaCaaaleqabaWaaSaaaeaacqaIZaWmaeaacqaIYaGmaaaaaaaakiab
% gUcaRiabek7aIjabdkfasjGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXn
% aaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeyypa0JaeGimaadaaiaawUhaaiab
% gkziUkGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIXa
% qmaeqaaOGaey4kaSIagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSba
% aSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGH9aqpcqaIWaamaaa!F878!
$$Note that since ${\theta _1},{\theta _2} \in [0,\pi )
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOqaaiabeI7aXnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqm
% aeqaaOGaeiilaWIaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGHii
% IZcqGGBbWwcqaIWaamcqGGSaalcqaHapaCcqGGPaqkaaa!4CC0!
$, the last equation seizes to yield any solution. Summarizing, the solutions are:
$$\begin{array}{l}1)\sin {\theta _1} = 0,\sin {\theta _2} = 0,\\2)\sin {\theta _1} = 0,\cos {\theta _2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{\alpha }{{{R^2}\beta }}} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}},\cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2}) = 0,\\3)\sin {\theta _2} = 0,\cos {\theta _1} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}{\left( {\frac{\alpha }{{{R^2}\beta }}} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}},\cos ({\phi _1} - {\phi _2}) = 0.\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfKttLearuqr1ngBPrgarmqr1ngBPrgitL
% xBI9gBamXvP5wqSXMqHnxAJn0BKvguHDwzZbqegm0B1jxALjhiov2D
% aeHbuLwBLnhiov2DGi1BTfMBaebbfv3ySLgzGueE0jxyaibaieYlf9
% irVeeu0dXdh9vqqj-hEeeu0xXdbba9frFj0-OqFfea0dXdd9vqaq-J
% frVkFHe9pgea0dXdar-Jb9hs0dXdbPYxe9vr0-vr0-vqpWqaaeaabi
% GaciaacaqabeaadaabauaaaOabaeqabaGaeGymaeJaeiykaKIagi4C
% amNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabigdaXaqabaGccq
% GH9aqpcqaIWaamcqGGSaalcyGGZbWCcqGGPbqAcqGGUbGBcqaH4oqC
% daWgaaWcbaGaeGOmaidabeaakiabg2da9iabicdaWiabcYcaSaqaai
% abikdaYiabcMcaPiGbcohaZjabcMgaPjabc6gaUjabeI7aXnaaBaaa
% leaacqaIXaqmaeqaaOGaeyypa0JaeGimaaJaeiilaWIagi4yamMaei
% 4Ba8Maei4CamNaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGH9aqp
% cqaIXaqmcqGHsisldaWcaaqaaiabigdaXaqaaiabikdaYaaadaqada
% qaamaalaaabaGaeqySdegabaGaemOuai1aaWbaaSqabeaacqaIYaGm
% aaGccqaHYoGyaaaacaGLOaGaayzkaaWaaWbaaSqabeaadaWcaaqaai
% abiodaZaqaaiabikdaYaaaaaGccqGGSaalcyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGG
% ZbWCcqGGOaakcqaHvpGzdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymaedabeaakiabgkHiTi
% abew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIYaGmaeqaaOGaeiykaKIaeyypa0JaeGim
% aaJaeiilaWcabaGaeG4mamJaeiykaKIagi4CamNaeiyAaKMaeiOBa4
% MaeqiUde3aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGH9aqpcqaIWaamcqGG
% SaalcyGGJbWycqGGVbWBcqGGZbWCcqaH4oqCdaWgaaWcbaGaeGymae
% dabeaakiabg2da9iabigdaXiabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaeGymaedabaGa
% eGOmaidaamaabmaabaWaaSaaaeaacqaHXoqyaeaacqWGsbGudaahaa
% WcbeqaaiabikdaYaaakiabek7aIbaaaiaawIcacaGLPaaadaahaaWc
% beqaamaalaaabaGaeG4mamdabaGaeGOmaidaaaaakiabcYcaSiGbco
% gaJjabc+gaVjabcohaZjabcIcaOiabew9aMnaaBaaaleaacqaIXaqm
% aeqaaOGaeyOeI0Iaeqy1dy2aaSbaaSqaaiabikdaYaqabaGccqGGPa
% qkcqGH9aqpcqaIWaamcqGGUaGlaaaa!B6F9!
$$